# Write a Python function to concatenate all elements (except the last element) of a given list into a string and return the string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my homework and I am a complete newbie to this.
Please help and explain in detail.

```
def conexclast(strlst):
    output = ""
    for elem in strlst:
       strng = str(elem)
       output = output+strng
    return ' '.join(strlst([0:-1]))
print("Enter data: ")
strlst= raw_input()
print(conexclast(strlst))
```

I dont know how to get the solution.

Comment: The task claims the input is a `list` but the code uses `raw_input()` to read in a `str` as input. Which one is it?

Comment: The function you define expects a list as argument. `strlst` is not a list, is a string, because `raw_input()` returns a string.

Comment: What should be used?

Comment: if you want a `list`, for multiple inputs you could do `strlst = raw_input().split()` for multiple string inputs on same line

Comment: That depends on you. You just need to be consistent within your code. Maybe edit your question to give us more context (your teacher gave you any constraints?) so we can help.

Comment: The code I mentioned is incorrect, I need to take the list as an input from the user and concatenate the string without displaying the last element of the list. What is the correct code with explanation

Comment: @Coder6969 looks like you only need to change the `return` statement to `return ' '.join(strlst[0:-1])`, appears to produce expected output

Comment: This is the entire question, nothing else is specifically mentioned.

Comment: @davedwards can you elaborate?

Comment: @Coder6969 If you want a detailed explanation of why dave's code will work, do like every other coder has to. Look at the docs, see [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def conexclast(strlst):
    '''
    function to concatenate all elements (except the last element) 
    of a given list into a string and return the string
    '''
    output = ""
    for elem in strlst:
       strng = str(elem)
       output = output+strng
    return ' '.join(strlst[0:-1])

print("Enter data: ")
strlst = raw_input().split()

print(conexclast(strlst))
```

The main correction is splitting the user's input `raw_input().split()` and:

`return ' '.join(strlst[0:-1])`

that slices the string, just need to remove the parentheses

See more for [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)